# How do I turn multiple data frames into a list, by specific prefix

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe

I have multiple data frames. Colnames in these data frames have specific prefix's. I would like to create a list from these data frames in a way that they are stored by their prefix.

---

For this example I have two data frames. Each with two different prefix's.

dput(head(FEB_gems)) output:

```
structure(list(GAME1_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", 
"paladin", "rouge", "sorcerer", "wizard"), class = "factor"), 
GAME1_Race = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("elf", 
"gnome", "human", "orc"), class = "factor"), GAME1_Alignment = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", "CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), 
GAME1_Level = c(6, 7, 6, 7, 7), GAME1_Alive = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "y", class = "factor"), GAME2_Class = structure(c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("bard", "cleric", "fighter", 
"monk", "wizard"), class = "factor"), GAME2_Race = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"
), class = "factor"), GAME2_Alignment = structure(c(4L, 2L, 
1L, 5L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", "CG", "LG", "NE", "NN"), class = "factor"), 
GAME2_Level = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5), GAME2_Alive = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

dput(head(MAR_gems)) output:

```
structure(list(GAME3_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("barbarian", 
"cleric", "monk", "ranger", "warlock"), class = "factor"), GAME3_Race = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"
), class = "factor"), GAME3_Alignment = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 2L), .Label = c("CE", "LG", "LN"), class = "factor"), GAME3_Level = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), GAME3_Alive = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("n", 
"y"), class = "factor"), GAME4_Class = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 
4L, 3L), .Label = c("fighter", "paladin", "rouge", "sorcerer", 
"wizard"), class = "factor"), GAME4_Race = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("dwarf", "elf", "half-elf", "human"), class = "factor"), 
GAME4_Alignment = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("CE", 
"CG", "LG", "LN"), class = "factor"), GAME4_Level = c(5, 
5, 5, 5, 5), GAME4_Alive = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("n", "y"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

Have made attempts at this including:

Separating the GAME info

```
CharecterInfo <- function(df){
  names(df) -> rons
  gsub(x=names(df), pattern = '_.*', replacement = '') -> subn
  subn[! duplicated(subn)] -> dupn
  return(dupn)
}

CharecterInfo(FEB_games) -> FCharInfo
CharecterInfo(MAR_games) -> MCharInfo
```

And then attempting to separate the data frames by specific prefix's.

```
for (i in FCharInfo) {
  assign(i, FCharInfo[, grep(paste0(i, '\\.'), colnames(FCharInfo), ignore.case = T)])
}
```

This did not work because my dimensions were incorrect but would just make many data frames rather than making a list.

I also made some attempts with the Map function in R, but to no success.

---

My ideal output would be:

1) A list containing 'GAME1_', 'GAME_2', 'GAME_3' and 'GAME_4' data as separate data frames.

2) Preferably in a function, as my real data is much larger than the data displayed here.

To make an attempt at illustrating the ideal list it would look like (I know the indents/ grey boxes are for code only, but I didn't know how else to illustrate the list on stackoverflow):

```
GameInfo

        Game1_
              GAME1_Class
              GAME1_Race
              GAME1_Alignment
              GAME1_Level
              GAME1_Alive
        Game2_
              GAME2_Class
              GAME2_Race
              GAME2_Alignment
              GAME2_Level
              GAME2_Alive
        Game3_
              GAME3_Class
              GAME3_Race
              GAME3_Alignment
              GAME3_Level
              GAME3_Alive
        Game4_
              GAME4_Class
              GAME4_Race
              GAME4_Alignment
              GAME4_Level
              GAME4_Alive
```

---

My prefix's are a bit complicated, these could include:

```
GAME_1.Class
GAME_10.Class
GAME_100.Class
```

I tried (based from Julian_hn's answer)

```
Gems <- list(FEB_gems = FEB_games, MAR_gems = MAR_games)
Gems.split <- lapply(Gems, function(df)
{
  Games <- unique(str_extract(names(df),"[:alnum:]+..."))
  List <- lapply(Games,function(name){return(df[,grep(name,names(df))])})
  names(List) <- Games
  return(List)
})
```

But this does not differentiate between 1, 100, or 1000. Could I separate  the prefix's after the '.' symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me, if your `FEB_gem` and `MAR_gem` `data.frames` are structured as a list.

```
library(stringr)
Gems <- list(FEB_gems=FEB_gems,MAR_gems=MAR_gems)
Gems.Split <- lapply(Gems,function(df)
{
  #old solution, requires GAME as name
  #Games <- unique(str_extract(names(df),"GAME[0-9]+"))

  #old solution 2: splits at "_"
  #Games <- unique(str_sub(str_extract(names(df),"[:alnum:]+_"),end=-2))

  #new solution: splits at "."
  Games <- unique(str_extract(names(df),"\\S+\\."))
  List <- lapply(Games,function(name){return(df[,grep(name,names(df),fixed=T)])})
  names(List) <- Games
  return(List)
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked well. But what if there were multiple different prefix's. For example in FEB_games if there were 'GAME1_', 'GAME2_' and in MAR_games there were 'Session1_' and 'Session2_'.

Comment: I've edited in a solution, that splits the name at "_" and doesn't care about what is before that as long as it's alphanumeric

Comment: I have added a new section at the bottom the question to show the complexity of the prefix's I am dealing with. Is it possible to split at the '.' instead of the '_'. Sorry I know this information was not made available before.

Comment: sure. you just have to change the regex inside the `str_extract`. I've added again to my post.

Comment: The output here groups together GAME_1.Class and GAME_10.Class in the GAME_1. list. Is there a method of making the regex more stringent. So that only GAME_10.Class, GAME_11.Class ect do not appear inside GAME_1.Class?

Comment: I've edited again to fix this bug. That was an error on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way using *tidyverse* :

```
fseq <- . %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>%
  gather(,,-rowid) %>%
  separate(key,c("game","col")) %>%
  spread(col,value) %>%
  select(-rowid)

map_dfr(list(FEB_gems, MAR_gems), fseq) %>%
  {split(.[-1],.$game)}

# $GAME1
# Alignment Alive    Class Level  Race
# 1        NE     y  paladin     6 human
# 3        CG     y  fighter     7   elf
# 5        CE     y   wizard     6   orc
# 7        NN     y sorcerer     7 human
# 9        LG     y    rouge     7 gnome
# 
# $GAME2
# Alignment Alive   Class Level     Race
# 2         NE     n fighter     5      elf
# 4         CG     y  wizard     5 half-elf
# 6         CE     y  cleric     5      elf
# 8         NN     y    monk     5    human
# 10        LG     y    bard     5    dwarf
# 
# $GAME3
# Alignment Alive     Class Level     Race
# 11        LG     y    cleric     1      elf
# 13        LG     y barbarian     1 half-elf
# 15        CE     y   warlock     1      elf
# 17        LN     n    ranger     1    human
# 19        LG     y      monk     1    dwarf
# 
# $GAME4
# Alignment Alive    Class Level     Race
# 12        CE     n  paladin     5      elf
# 14        CG     y  fighter     5 half-elf
# 16        CE     y   wizard     5      elf
# 18        LN     y sorcerer     5    human
# 20        LG     y    rouge     5    dwarf
# 
# Warning messages:
#   1: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
# they will be dropped 
# 2: attributes are not identical across measure variables;
# they will be dropped
```

Answer (score 1):

*Another* possible (nested) `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

t_tib <- function(df) {
  as_tibble(cbind(nms = names(df), t(df)))
}

GameInfo <- t_tib(FEB_gems) %>% 
  bind_rows(t_tib(MAR_gems)) %>% 
  gather(rowid, val, -nms) %>% 
  separate(nms, into = c("Game", "var")) %>% 
  spread(var, val) %>% 
  select(-rowid) %>%
  select(1, 4, 6, 2, 5, 3) %>% 
  nest(-Game)
```

(Removed `bind_cols` per Moody_Mudskipper suggestion.)

Comment: `bind_cols` makes the assumption that both data frames have the same amount of rows, which might be the case as it is in the sample data but it's a strong assumption.